# Importing txt files with missing text qualifiers

Tags: r, csv, data-import

I have some text file (in csv format) that have some missing text qualifiers like in the second row, five column of the following (AMM):

```
"A",4,"","","HIGH STREET, 22","","","L6","3AA"
"B",2957136105,98,"M12ASE7569",AMM",1,,,"F",,20010514,"CR"
"C","T","UNKNOWN","",19000101
"D",4
```

I managed to spot the line with the inconsistencies by looping through the columns this code: (just save the above in a txt)

```
library(plyr)
a <- readLines(path) # 
a <- rbind.fill(lapply(a, function(x) read.table(text=x, sep=",", as.is=T, quote="")))
> which(sapply(gregexpr("\"", a[,5]), length)==1 & grepl("\"", a[,5]))
[1] 1 2
```

However in my files there are commas inside field (due to addresses), therefore I also get false positive...

Have some of you ever faced such issues? If so, what have you come up with?

Comment: I think the answer will have to be customized to the source .csv file. For example, if it is what you have above, then there is no way to predict what type of value should go in what column or how many columns there should be on a given line. That would make it difficult, because "Moscow, Russia" is ambiguous (could be "Moscow","Russia").

Comment: @JamesPringle hi thanks. I was worried about that... I agree that with the above method and the above data it's probably impossible. I'm asking actually for a (completely) different way. I tried with `read.table(path, fill=T)` but `R 3.0.1` imports a `0 rows` df...

Comment: In these situations I've used `read.table(*, fill=FALSE)`, noted the row number where it barfed, and manually fixed the file. Repeat until the entire file is read successfully. Hopefully there aren't too many such rows....

Comment: Are your data really *that* badly formed? From the sample lines you shared above, how is *any* program going to be able to guess how many columns need to be imported? I would suggest looking at [`csvclean` from *csvkit*](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvclean.html), but I doubt that even that script would be able to help in a situation like this....

Comment: @HongOoi thanks, manual fixing is how I'm doing... I was just thinking in doing some kind of cleansing tool.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes they are :-). Even though  the only actual issue is this missing text qualifier... different columns per line is (unfortunately) the way the data I deal with are supposed to be... the first column indicates the name of the table that row is going to go.

Comment: If your problem is really only missing quotation marks, maybe use something like this to identify your problem lines up front: `x <- readLines("myFile"); sapply(gregexpr("\"", x), length) %% 2`. That is, read in your lines, use `gregexpr` to count how many times it encounters a quotation mark, make sure that's divisible by two. If it's not, you *definitely* have unbalanced quotation marks. This won't catch all problem cases, though--for instance, cases where there are, say, two unbalanced quotation marks in your data.